# VBScript: How can I trim a number to 4 decimal places but not round it?

Tags: vbscript

My code currently looks like this:

```
FormatNumber((CDbl(0.05935)),4)
```

The returned value is 0.0594 rather than 0.0593 which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try parsing this number to string then trimming it and again parsing back to float.

example:

```
v = 100.0097

x = Str$(v)    ' Gives " 100.0097"
```

//This adds a leading space for positive numbers
or

```
x = CStr(v)    ' Gives "100.0097"
```

and then trim it as your need

```
finalstr = LEFT(variable, (LEN(variable)-4))
```

then parse it to float

```
finaltrimed = CDbl(finalstr)
```